# return back laravel function not working on server

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

I have problem with my laravel project, when validator false return back function run well on localhost, but on the server it return to root url , somebody may help me figure it out?
My controller like this:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('get'))
        return view('employees.form_edit', ['user' => User::find($id)]);
    else {
        $rules = [
            'name' => 'required',
            'full_name' => 'required',
            'id_number' => 'required',
            'date_of_birth' => 'required',
            'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048'
        ];
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);
        if ($validator->fails()) {
            return redirect()->back()
                ->withErrors($validator)
              ;
        }

        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->position = $request->position;
        $user->full_name = $request->full_name;
        $user->id_number = $request->id_number;
        $user->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
        $user->status = $request->status;
        $img_current = 'upload/avatar/' .$request->input('img_current');
        if (!empty($request->file('avatar'))) {
            $file_name = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
            $user->image = $file_name;
            $request->file('avatar')->move('upload/avatar/',$file_name);
            if (File::exists($img_current)) {
                File::delete($img_current);
            }
        }else{
            echo "no file";
        }
        $user->save();
        return redirect('listEmployees');

    }
}
```

My route:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'listEmployees'], function () {
  Route::match(['get', 'post'], 'update/{id}', 'EmployeesController@update');
});
```

Comment: I dont see any `return back();`

Comment: i also using return back(); but get the same error

Comment: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code I have

**CONTROLLER**

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('get'))
      return view('employees.form_edit', ['user' => User::find($id)]);
    else {
      $_data = $request->validate([
        'name' => ['required'].
        'full_name' => ['required'],
        'id_number' => ['required'],
        'date_of_birth' => ['required'],
        'avatar' => ['mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif', 'max:2048'],
        'position' => ['nullable'],
        'status' => ['nullable']
      ])

      $img_current = 'upload/avatar/' .$request->input('img_current');
      if (!empty($request->file('avatar'))) {
          $file_name = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
          $data['image'] = $file_name;
          $request->file('avatar')->move('upload/avatar/',$file_name);
          if (File::exists($img_current)) {
              File::delete($img_current);
          }
      }else{
          echo "no file";
      }

      $user = User::find($id);
      $user->update($_data);
      return redirect('listEmployees');
    }
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@if ($errors->any())
  <div class="alert alert-warning">
    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
      {{$error}} <br>
    @endforeach
  </div>
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you go further with this problem you need to clean up your code a little bit.
First of all you dont need to check the `request->method` if you have already made the route "Route::update" (laravel takes care of it).
Second: use laravel form-request and make your controller much more cleaner and readable(`php artisan make:request ModelNameRequest`)
Third: you dont need to redirect user to manually if you want to redirect to `back()`, again laravel takes care of it, it will redirect `back()` if the validator fails with and array of $errors.
any ways this is the code that may work:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
    $rules = [
        'name' => 'required',
        'full_name' => 'required',
        'id_number' => 'required',
        'date_of_birth' => 'required',
        'avatar' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif|max:2048'
    ];

    // if the validation failes, laravel redirects back with a collection of $errors
    $this->validate($request->all(), $rules);

    // you probably want to use User::create($request->only('input1', 'input2', ...);
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->position = $request->position;
    $user->full_name = $request->full_name;
    $user->id_number = $request->id_number;
    $user->date_of_birth = $request->date_of_birth;
    $user->status = $request->status;
    $img_current = 'upload/avatar/' .$request->input('img_current');

    // use a good package for storing your files like Mediable to make it easy.
    if (!empty($request->file('avatar'))) {
        $file_name = $request->file('avatar')->getClientOriginalName();
        $user->image = $file_name;
        $request->file('avatar')->move('upload/avatar/',$file_name);
        if (File::exists($img_current)) {
            File::delete($img_current);
        }
    }else{
        //TODO: you should not echo some thing here, you should use session()->flash()
        session()->flash('message', 'You did not select any file.');
    }
    $user->save();
    return redirect('listEmployees');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve this problem by change redirect function to

```
 return redirect()->action(
                'EmployeesController@update', ['id' => $id]
            )
```

thank all guy